# Change First Name process task is getting rejected

Tags: logging, oim

This is a custom connector implementation wherein we are facing an issue in the update task. `Change First Name` task is getting triggered but its returning with exception saying `Unknown response returned`

also the logs are not generated for these process tasks though the logs are coming for `Create User` operation.

Also as per the standard the task to status response mapping is done correctly :
setting unknown response.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check the Process Definition.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to propogate the changes is to use a copy-string adapter, is that what is mapped to the Change First Name process task?

input = User definition first name

output = process data -> first name field?

It sounds like the adapter being used expects a response code.(ala SUCCESS or Complete)